# python.el: auto save buffer before python-shell-send-buffer

Tags: python

Can python.el be set up in a way that it will automatically save the current buffer when python-shell-send-buffer is called (e.g. by C-c C-c)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sure can be!

First, create a function that saves the buffer before calling `python-shell-send-buffer`:

```lisp
(defun my-python-shell-send-buffer ()
  "Save the current buffer before calling `python-shell-send-buffer'."
  (interactive)
  (save-buffer)
  (python-shell-send-buffer))
```

The `interactive` line allows you to call the function using `M-x`.  I suspect the other lines are self-explanatory.  If not, read about them using `C-h f`.

Next, override `C-c C-c` in `python-mode` with the new function:

```
(define-key python-mode-map (kbd "C-c C-c") 'my-python-shell-send-buffer)
```

After executing each of these lines, when you reload `python-mode`, `C-c C-c` will work as you desire.  Put these lines in `init.el` and this will be the new behavior for `python-mode`.

Comment: Cool, thanks! I had to make a minor adjustment, though, in order to avoid an error message: `(add-hook 'python-mode-hook
          (lambda () (define-key python-mode-map (kbd "C-c C-c") 'my-python-shell-send-buffer)))`